# aws lambda function to disable and delete CloudFront distribution in python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudfront

I am working on a Lambda Function written in python and using boto3 to call AWS APIs.

Work of lambda function as follows -

1. Get the CloudFront Distribution list.
2. Get the CloudFront Distribution ID.
3. Get the CloudFront Distribution Config of those distribution which older than 60 minutes.
4. Create a JSON file of CloudFront Distribution Config.
5. Read the JSON file and make a dictionary array to pass in CF update API.
6. Call Update Distribution API and pass the required parameters.

Reference Document is - [AWS Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#CloudFront.Client.update_distribution)

Now the problem is, the update API giving an error to me as far as the requested data is correct.

Please find my python lambda function code link -
[Lambda function to disable and delete CloudFront destribution](https://github.com/rahulgaikwadsipl/lambda_delete_cloud_front_python/blob/master/delete.py)

Here is the error I am getting while updating (disable) CloudFront distribution via update API-

```
Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "CallerReference"
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "Origins"
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "DefaultCacheBehavior"
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "Comment"
Missing required parameter in DistributionConfig: "Enabled"
Unknown parameter in DistributionConfig: "ETag", must be one of: CallerReference, Aliases, DefaultRootObject, Origins, OriginGroups, DefaultCacheBehavior, CacheBehaviors, CustomErrorResponses, Comment, Logging, PriceClass, Enabled, ViewerCertificate, Restrictions, WebACLId, HttpVersion, IsIPV6Enabled
Unknown parameter in DistributionConfig: "DistributionConfig", must be one of: CallerReference, Aliases, DefaultRootObject, Origins, OriginGroups, DefaultCacheBehavior, CacheBehaviors, CustomErrorResponses, Comment, Logging, PriceClass, Enabled, ViewerCertificate, Restrictions, WebACLId, HttpVersion, IsIPV6Enabled
Unknown parameter in DistributionConfig: "ResponseMetadata", must be one of: CallerReference, Aliases, DefaultRootObject, Origins, OriginGroups, DefaultCacheBehavior, CacheBehaviors, CustomErrorResponses, Comment, Logging, PriceClass, Enabled, ViewerCertificate, Restrictions, WebACLId, HttpVersion, IsIPV6Enabled
```

The above error message shown the parameters are missing but I have checked the request has all the required parameters, I didn't understand why its giving error.

If someone has any solution for this please share or any other idea to disable and delete CloudFront distribution from AWS Lambda.

Comment: Try `update_distribution(DistributionConfig=dist_list['DistributionConfig'], ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `dist_list` variable is the returned value from calling `cloudfrontclient.get_distribution_config(...)`. This is not actually the distribution config. It's a dictionary containing the distribution config.

Change your update call as follows:

```
dc = dist_list['DistributionConfig']
dist_update = cloudfrontclient.update_distribution(DistributionConfig=dc, ...)
```